jot notes on web pages (Browser Extension)
Simply, I need a Chrome extension that can write "Hello World" and other notes on a webpage/webpages. These notes are private and important.
(Obviously if the link goes down, 404, 505, whatever the notes stay.)
Requirement:

'Free forever' while BigTech not required (no facebook/google etc)
there must be a table of all notes (organized  by timestamp/domain etc), not just display them when I'm on that link

Bonus:

log edits
all notes are private by default, at the same time I want leeway while I'm using a public computer
works on firefox
works on non-webpages links
notes publishable

